# PHP SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, mysql

I don't understand why such a mistake appeares here, could you help me, please?
Mistake:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idT_Inf' cannot be null

Maybe i need to change some details in the database? yes, i set "NOT NULL" condition to each column in the database but i dont leave any gap in the form (from in Administrativni prostredi) empty. Mb some of you met such  kind of problem. Thanks in advance :)

PraceSDB.php:

```
     <?php
    class Connection{
    public function __construct(){
    try{
    $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=brichevg','brichevg','wa1');
    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    }

    public function addNote(){
    $name= $_POST['tourName'];

    $path= $_POST['path'];

    $days= $_POST['days'];

    $hotel=$_POST['hotel'];

    $priceSingleRoom= $_POST['priceSingleRoom'];

    $priceDoubleRoom= $_POST['priceDoubleRoom'];

    $priceBreakfast= $_POST['priceBreakfast'];

    $priceLunch= $_POST['priceLunch'];

    $priceDinner= $_POST['priceDinner'];

    $cityTourPrice= $_POST['priceTour'];

    $totalTourPrice= $_POST['totalTourPrice'];

    $date= $_POST['date'];

    $sql_1= "INSERT INTO Tour_Info (name, path, Hotel, Price_of_single_room, Price_of_double_room, Price_of_breakfast,
    Price_of_lunch, Price_of_dinner, City_tour, Total_tour_price, City_tour_price, Amount_of_days) 
    VALUES (:name, :path, :hotel, :priceSingleRoom, :priceDoubleRoom, :priceBreakfast, :priceLunch, :priceDinner, :cityTour,
    :totalTourPrice, :cityTourPrice, :days ) ";

    try{
    $prep_1=$this->db->prepare($sql_1);
    $prep_1->bindParam(":name",$name);
    $prep_1->bindParam(":path",$path);
    $prep_1->bindParam(":days",$days);
    $prep_1->bindParam(":hotel",$hotel);
    $prep_1->bindParam(":priceSingleRoom",$priceSingleRoom);
    $prep_1->bindParam(":priceDoubleRoom",$priceDoubleRoom);
    $prep_1->bindParam(":priceBreakfast",$priceBreakfast);
    $prep_1->bindParam(":priceLunch",$priceLunch);
    $prep_1->bindParam(":priceDinner",$priceDinner);
    $prep_1->bindParam(":cityTour",$cityTourIncluded);
    $prep_1->bindParam(":cityTourPrice",$cityTourPrice);
    $prep_1->bindParam(":totalTourPrice",$totalTourPrice);
    $prep_1->execute();

    $res=$this->db->query('SELECT @@IDENTITY');
    $row=$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $idecko=$row[0];

    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $sql_1 . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }




    $sql_2="INSERT INTO Tour(idT_inf,date) VALUES (:idT_inf, :date)";


    try{
    $prep_2=$this->db->prepare($sql_2);
    $prep_2->bindParam(":date",$date);
    $prep_2->bindParam(":idT_inf",$idecko);
    $prep_2->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $sql_2 . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    }
    }
```

Administrativni_prostredi.php:

```
    <?php
    require('praceSDB.php');
    $connection= new Connection();
    if(isset($_POST['submitNewTour'])){
    $connection->addNote();
    }
    ?>


    <html>
    <head><Title>Administrative interface</title>
    <meto charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h3>Add new tour</h3>


    <form method="post" action="">
    <p><label>Tour name:</label>
     <input type="text",name="tourName"/>
    </p>

    <p><label>Tour path:</label>
     <input type="text",name="path"/>
    </p>


    <p><label>Amount of days:</label>
     <input type="text",name="days"/>
    </p>


    <p><label>Hotel:</label>
     <input type="text",name="hotel"/>
    </p>

    <p><label>Hotel price(single room):</label>
     <input type="text",name="priceSingleRoom"/>
    </p>

    <p><label>Hotel price(double room):</label>
     <input type="text",name="priceDoubleRoom"/>
    </p>

    <p><label>Breakfast price:</label>
     <input type="text",name="priceBreakfast"/>
    </p>

    <p><label>Lunch price:</label>
     <input type="text",name="priceLunch"/>
    </p>

    <p><label>Dinner price:</label>
     <input type="text",name="priceDinner"/>
    </p>

    <p><label>City tour price:</label>
     <input type="text",name="priceTour"/>
    </p>

    <p><label>City tour included:</label>
     Yes: <input type="radio" name="cityTour" value="yes" /> No:<input type="radio",name="cityTour" value="no"/>
    </p>
    <p><label>Tour price (transport,agency servise): </label>
    <input type="text",name="totalTourPrice"/>
    </p>

    <p><label>Trip's date:</label>
     <input type="text",name="date"/>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submitNewTour"/>

    </form>


    <h3>All actual tours</h3>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: when you debug are idt_inf and name null?

Comment: why do you have commas `,` in the middle of all your inputs -> `<input type="text",name="tourName"/>`?

Comment: Sean, thank u, i've taken the commas out

Answer (score 0):

```
$prep_1->bindParam(":cityTour",$cityTourIncluded);`
```

Where is `$cityTourIncluded` defined?

Edit:  This doesn't seem to be your problem but it shows a problem.  You probably would have been able to figure this out if you had notices displayed or logged.  So I'm guessing you'll have other notices and errors displayed cluing you in on your problem.

Comment: Devon,thank you for the advise. I missed cityTourIncluded, i added it and the first mistake disappeared. The second one (about 'idT_inf') is still there. I hesitate if i did this in a right way: $res=$this->db->query('SELECT @@IDENTITY');
    $row=$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $idecko=$row[0];

Comment: I need the ID of cityTour Informtion whic is the first insert. Its an auto_incremented id

Comment: Does the first insert succeed?  Why are you using `SELECT @@IDENTITY` instead of the `lastInsertId()` method?  Does MySQL support `@IDENTITY`?

Comment: yes, it supports.i solved the problem this way: $res=$this->db->query('SELECT @@IDENTITY');
$row=$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$idecko=implode($row);   it works :)

Comment: @Zhenya you just seem to be doing a lot of extra work for something that is built into PDO with `lastInsertId()`.